# How to load all variables from a configparser file?

Tags: python, configparser

I am trying to load all variables defined in a text file using configparser. I have managed to load them using a dictionary but I would like them to be loaded directly as variables. Is there a clean way to do it?

```
###file.txt##########
[Section1]
var1 = 10.0
var2 = 25.0
####################

import configparser

cp = configparser.ConfigParser()   
configFilePath = r'file.txt'
cp.read(configFilePath)

d = dict(cp.items('Section1'))

for a in d:
    d[a]=float(d[a])
```

now I can get var1 as `d['var1']` but I want to just be able to get it as a variable

I want to do the following:

```
print(var1)

#output ---> 10.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
for a in d:
    exec("%s=%s" % (a,float(d[a])))
```

Saying that, I won't recommend doing that, it will make your code very messy and hard to read and follow

Comment: Thank you. If it is not asking too much, could give me a hint about any other way to do it more cleanly? I hasn't to be related to configparser. Would be importing a .py file with the declared variables any better?

Comment: yes you can do a config.py file and then do something like
`import config`